# read only attribute is safe in django forms?

Tags: django

Setting read only attrs for django forms is safe?. In my django projects I do something like this:

```
def someUpdateView(request):
 form = EmployeeForm(instance=Employeem.objects.get(pk=1))
 return render...
```

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm)
 declaring here read only attrs field by widgets dict in Meta class        or in init method (i.e. pk fields or other fields like email for keeping inmutable).
```

But what if an user opens web browser inspector mode and edits html field value or deletes read only attribute? during form.save() django will save the new value even it was read only (from html) and if this happens, there is a way to handle that?.

Comment: Why not exclude the field from the form?

Comment: but if it is a primary key things like form.save() will not work